Is there a way to create a dataLayer variable in GTM, pointing to a nested object?
Is there a way to create a dataLayer variable in GTM, pointing to a nested object?
I've tried to have eventModel.items[0].name, but it returns as undefined even if eventModel.items is an array with a correct object inside.
I'm using Version 2 for this variable. Is there a specific syntax/way to access something nested in an array that deep?

I just had to use:
eventModel.items.0.name

Instead of:
eventModel.items[0].name

in my Data Layer variable.

See if this can be helpful:

Create a data layer variable v2 with the generic eventModel
In our example, we will use "ecommerce" assuming a Datalayer push like this one:



dataLayer.push({
  event: 'view_item',
  ecommerce: {
    currency: 'USD',
    items: [{
      item_id: 'SKU123',  // What we're extracting
      item_name: 'Cool Product',
      price: 29.99
      // ... other product data
    }]
  }
});



Once you create this variable then you should create a new Custom Javascript variable and use this code (in this example we want to fetch the item_id of the first product)


function() {
  var ecomm = {{ecommerce}};
  if (!ecomm || !ecomm.items || !ecomm.items.length) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return ecomm.items[0].item_id || '';
}



In this way if you use GTM preview and select the DL Push which is supposed to have your eventModel and look into variables you should get the variable and not undefined
Let me know if this works, otherwise let's debug this, maybe you could share your eventModel DataLayer Push?
fetch_item_id
this is better explained in this article: https://blog.assertionhub.com/articles/extract-first-product-id-from-ga4-ecommerce-data-layer
